# Why doesn't $hash.key syntax work inside the ExpandString method?

Tags: powershell, syntax, powershell-3.0

The following Powershell script demonstrates the issue:

```
$hash = @{'a' = 1; 'b' = 2}
Write-Host $hash['a']        # => 1
Write-Host $hash.a           # => 1

# Two ways of printing using quoted strings.
Write-Host "$($hash['a'])"   # => 1
Write-Host "$($hash.a)"      # => 1

# And the same two ways Expanding a single-quoted string.
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString('$($hash[''a''])') # => 1
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString('$($hash.a)')      # => Oh no!

Exception calling "ExpandString" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At line:1 char:1
+ $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString('$($hash.a)')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException
```

Anyone know why the `$hash.key` syntax works everywhere but inside explicit expansion? Can this be fixed, or do I have to suck it up and live with the `$hash[''key'']` syntax?

Comment: It's actually worse than that - I can't get *any* actual subexpression expanded using this syntax, only simple things like $($foo) work e.g. '$(Get-Date | select -expand DayOfWeek)' will raise same exception. Suggest reporting it on connect, IMO that's breaking change/ bug.

Comment: Reporting it on where? I don't know what 'connect' means in this context.

Comment: Sorry, should be more specific...: http://connect.microsoft.com/powershell -> best place to report such issues.

Comment: Is there a workaround for now? This seems to fail in Win7 and work correctly in Win8.

Comment: I know of no good workaround for executing methods in ExpandString. However, there is a good chance this was broken in the Powershell v3 beta, but fixed in the final. I have not yet installed the final version of PS3 to confirm this.

Comment: This is rather late, but if you arrive here and wish this resolved, please vote up the [bug report I made](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/755270/string-expansion-in-double-quotes-behaves-differently-than-executioncontext-invokecommand-expandstring) on it last June.

Comment: Definitely not resolved in v4

Comment: [Resolved in v5](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/755270/string-expansion-in-double-quotes-behaves-differently-than-executioncontext-invokecommand-expandstring)! I'm happy.

Answer (score 4):

I use this method, since this bug exists in v4 (not in v5)

```
function render() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ( [parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)] [string] $str)

    #buggy
    #$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($str)

    "@`"`n$str`n`"@" | iex
}
```

Usage for your example:

```
  '$($hash.a)' | render
```

Answer (score 1):

The ExpandString api is not exactly meant for use from PowerShell scripts, it was added more for C# code.  It's still a bug that your example doesn't work (and I think it's been fixed in V4), but it does mean there is a workaround - one that I recommend for general use.

Double quoted strings effectively (but not literally) call ExpandString.  So the following should be equivalent:

```
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString('$($hash.a)')
"$($hash.a)"
```

Comment: So how do you delay processing of a double-quoted string? The entire reason for doing this is so that variables that do not exist when the string `'$($hash.a)'` is defined can be embedded into the result at runtime.

Comment: The processing of a double quoted string happens when the expression is executed, not when it is parsed.  In other words, the processing happens like it would if you called the ExpandString api.

Comment: Which doesn't answer the question. How would you encode $str so that this example writes 'After'? `$hash['a'] = 'Before': $str = '$($hash.a)': $hash['a'] = 'After': Write.Host $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($str)`

Comment: I wouldn't write code like that because I find it fragile.  But there are several options.  $sb = { "$($hash.a)" }; $hash['a'] = 'After'; write-host (& $sb).  In this example, you could define a function instead of using a script block.  Another option is to use Invoke-Expression which I strongly discourage, but it looks like: $str = '"$($hash.a)"'; $hash['a'] = 'After'; Write-Host (iex $str)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to store text that prompts the user in a text file. I wanted to be able to have variables in the text file that are expanded from my script.

My settings are stored in a PSCustomObject called $profile and so in my text I was trying to do something like:

```
Hello $($profile.First) $($profile.Last)!!!
```

and then from my script I was trying to do:

```
$profile=GetProfile #Function returns PSCustomObject 
$temp=Get-Content -Path "myFile.txt"
$myText=Join-String $temp
$myText=$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($myText)
```

which of course left me with the error

> Exception calling "ExpandString" with "1" argument(s): "Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object."

Finally I figured out I only needed to to store the PSCustomObject values I want in regular old variables, change the text file to use those instead of the object.property version and everything worked nicely:

```
$profile=GetProfile #Function returns PSCustomObject 
$First=$profile.First
$Last=$profile.Last
$temp=Get-Content -Path "myFile.txt"
$myText=Join-String $temp
$myText=$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($myText)
```

And in the text I changed to

> Hello $First $Last!!!