# Expand Hash variable while reading file content in PoSH 4.0

Tags: powershell, hashtable, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a xml file where i have defined some HashTable variables, when i read the content at runtime they should be resolved.

XML File

```
<variable>
    <clientname>$($hfinfo.hf)</clientname>
</variable>
```

It was working in the Powershell 2.0, the snippet is below.

### PowerShell 2.0

```
$hash=@{};
$hash.add("hf","HFDetail_Random_Name")
[xml]$xmlcontent=[xml]($ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString((Get-Content ($xmlFilePath))))
```

### Powershell 4.0

In PoSH 4.0, when i execute the same command i am getting the error

```
Exception calling "ExpandString" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

Comment: It seems that this method might have changed behaviour in every version of PowerShell. At least there seem to be a bug on Connect for more than one change; [1 -> 2](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/496932/powershell-expandstring-bug) and [2 -> 3](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/755270/string-expansion-in-double-quotes-behaves-differently-than-executioncontext-invokecommand-expandstring). Perhaps 4.0 works the same as 3.0? The 2 -> 3 bug linked above has a workaround posted. I haven't tested it, though. Please let us know your findings!

Comment: Bug still exists in 4, but not in 5. See universal solution in http://stackoverflow.com/a/29005535/82660

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following method instead:

[xml]$xmlcontent=[xml]($ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.**InvokeScript**((Get-Content ($xmlFilePath))))