# Expand variable in file

Tags: powershell, variables

We're trying to create input files for a script of ours instead of hard coding the text of an e-mail within the code with here strings (`@"E-mail text"@`). However, it seems really difficult to populate a variable that is not plain and simple like `$MyVariable` but needs to be addressed like `$MyVariable.User.Name`.

Anyhow, the code below demonstrates the problem.

**HTML Input file**

```
Dear $($Object.User.GivenName)
Thank you for joining the program.
```

**Code**

```
$SamAccountNameManager = 'Mike'
$SamAccountNameUser = 'Bob'
$File = 'C:\Test.html'

$Object = [PSCustomObject]@{
    User    = Get-ADUser $SamAccountNameUser -Properties GivenName
    Manager = Get-ADUser $SamAccountNameManager -Properties GivenName
}

$Template = Get-Content $File
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($Template)
```

**Error**

```
Exception calling "ExpandString" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an obj
ect."
```

How is it possible to use the variable `$Object.User.GivenName` in the text file and have it populated with the proper value?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error from the example given (tested PowerShell 2 and 5).

Comment: Tried it again just to be sure and still the same error. Using PowerShell 4.0 on Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()` expands variables in a string. It does not evaluate complex expressions. Basically, to make things work the way you want you need to create individual variables

```
$GivenName = Get-ADUser $SamAccountNameUser -Properties GivenName |
             Select-Object -Expand GivenName
$Manager   = Get-ADUser $SamAccountNameManager -Properties GivenName |
             Select-Object -Expand GivenName

$Template = Get-Content $File | Out-String
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($Template)
```

and use those in your template:

```
Dear $GivenName
Thank you for joining the program.
```

Comment: Very strange, because when I try a calculation like `Dear $(5*5)` this works fine. Only not for variables with a dot... If there's no real solution then I guess your workaround is the only way forward. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Found a workaround [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605772/why-doesnt-hash-key-syntax-work-inside-the-expandstring-method) by usiing  "@`"`n$Template`n`"@" | Invoke-Expression.

Comment: `Invoke-Expression` will execute arbitrary code, so I wouldn't recommend doing that.